# Here's a "What am I?"

Tags: riddle

> I do not move, but I change every moment. 
>   I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise.
>   I am tangible, and I exist.
>   But what I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist.
>   **What am I?**

Comment: Can we get an answer to this please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are:

> Time.

I do not move but I change every moment.

> Time doesn't move, but it's always changing.

I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise.

> Some people need the time they have, and others have more time than they need.

What I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist.

> The passing of time from moment to moment is itself intangible, and "time" as a physical entity doesn't really exist.

**EDIT:**
Based on the edit to the description I came up with a new answer.

I think you are:

> A watch/clock.

I do not move, but I change every moment.

> A watch/clock is inanimate, but time is always changing.

I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise.

> If you need the time then it's useful, but you don't always need to know the time.

I am tangible, and I exist.

> Yes it exists.

But what I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist.

> The passing of time, however, is intangible and time itself does not exist.

Comment: Not quite what I was going for. Updated the riddle to provide additional context.

Comment: I added an answer based on the updated description.

Comment: This is close enough to the correct answer that I'm willing to accept it. I was thinking of a >sundial

Comment: Ahhhh, that's a good one, and makes sense regarding the last clue.

Comment: The hands of a clock *do* move. However, if you specify that it's a *digital* clock, that's no longer a concern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> A pixel (of a display monitor).

"I do not move, but I change every moment."

> Pixels are always in the same spot on the screen. They are redrawn many times per second, usually 60 on most computer monitors. This is usually more visible when playing a video, but always happens.

"I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise."

> When viewing a high-resolution graphic (or a low-resolution one with low scaling), an individual pixel defines part of the image and makes a difference in the overall characteristics of the image displayed. But when viewing an image with high scaling, an individual pixel will often become redundant to other surrounding pixels.

"I am tangible, and I exist."

> Of course, pixels exist.

"But what I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist."

> To light up each and every pixel, a monitor needs a video signal, which is intangible. Obviously, the image being displayed by the grid of pixels doesn't actually exist; the brain blends them together to make it look like an object is being displayed.

Comment: Hmm if this is the correct answer, I feel that this question's a dup...

Comment: @NL628 Of what?

Comment: Not sure I can't find it :(( Good answer though :D

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> Money

"I do not move, but I change every moment."

> Sits in bank accounts but the value changes with inflation / exchange rates.

"I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise."

> When you need to buy something then it's useful. Otherwise it's just sitting there in a wallet.

"I am tangible, and I exist."

> Currency does exist in paper and coins.

"But what I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist."

> Money relies on TRUST and VALUE is not a physical object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be

> Luminosity of universe

As,

I do not move, but I change every moment.

> It exists and changes continuously but on its own, it does not move

I'm useful to some sometimes, and redundant to others otherwise.

> It's useful during daytime(of sun) and not so during night (Perhaps this explains that part... *to others otherwise*)

I am tangible, and I exist.

> It can be measured in Lux and exists(As we can visually feel it)

But what I need is intangible, and what I provide doesn't exist.

> Luminosity requires presence of objects(which are countless/innumerable in the universe....rather *intangible*) to prove its presence(to us) and it provides visibility, which is physically not existing

A kind of stretch...in some cases, though.